# Steady current in ohmic materials implies charge density is 0

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

I'm working through Purcell and Morin's "Electricity and Magnetism", and in the chapter on electrical currents, Purcell writes,

"In a region where the conductivity $\sigma$ is constant, the seady current condition $\text{div } \bf{J}$  $= 0$ together with $\bf{J}= \sigma \bf{E}$ implies that div $\bf{E}$ $= 0$ also. This tells us that the charge density is $0$ in that region."

I followed this chain of relations, but I can't wrap my mind around this. How can there be 0 charge density inside a steady current? Wouldn't that mean that there is no charge flowing?
I would really appreciate an explanation of how charge density can be 0 here.

Comment: Could you define what "E" is ? Emf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vanishing local charge density does not necessarily mean that there is no charge. A metal wire is charge neutral, i.e. the charge density is zero everywhere in the wire. In the case of current in metals, electrons with negative charge are free to move, while positive charged ions are fixed in position. Since the metal is charge neutral, the density of positive and negative charge is zero. But since applying an electric field only causes the negative charges to move, you get net current flow.

The condition $\nabla\mathbf{j}=0$ means that if you integrate the current density over the surface of a cylinder, you get zero. This means all of the electrons that flow in through one end cap also flow out on the other side (assume that the cylinder is oriented with the symmetry axis along $\mathbf{j}$). This you can derive from Gauss' Law of integration.

In order to observe current, you don't need a varying charge density, but only a net charge flow.

Answer (score 0):

> I followed this chain of relations, but I can't wrap my mind around
> this. How can there be 0 charge density inside a steady current?

For constant current, the divergence of the current density is zero because the amount of current leaving a cross section of wire is equal to the amount of current entering the same cross.

> How can there be 0 charge density inside a steady current?

Constant current tells us that the amount of charge entering a region per unit time has to equal the amount of charge exiting the same region per unit time. Thus, in that region, the net charge per unit time is zero. If the net charge in a region is zero, the charge density in that region must also be zero.

> Wouldn't that mean that there is no charge flowing?

No, just that the difference between the charge entering and exiting a region is zero so that no net charge in the region.

Hope this helps.